# Не учитывать первый и последний символ в регулярках

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый вечер.

Можете подсказать как в регулярке вырезать первый и последний символ? Вот допустим есть такая регулярка:

```
preg_match_all('/[\:]{1}[\w\-]{1,}[\:]{1}/i', ':blah-blah-blah-blah:', $print, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($print);
```

Выводится:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => :blah-blah-blah-blah:
        )
)
```

т.е. чтоб выводилось без двоеточия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Выделите скобками:**

```
[\:]{1}([\w\-]{1,})[\:]{1}
       ^          ^
```

Затем:

```
preg_match_all('/[\:]{1}([\w\-]{1,})[\:]{1}/i', ':blah-blah-blah-blah:', $print, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($print);
```

Получится:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => :blah-blah-blah-blah:
        )
[1] => Array   //то что нужно:
        (
            [0] => blah-blah-blah-blah
        )
)
```

**N.B. Можно упростить до:**

```
[\:]([\w\-]+)[\:]
```

`{1}` - в принципе не нужны, a `{1,}` можно заменить на `+`

**Средствами PHP:**

Воспользуйтесь функцией [trim](http://www.php.su/trim), она удаляет указанные символы с начала и конца строки

```
trim(':blah-blah-blah-blah:',':')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, мне именно регулярки и интересовали.

Answer (score 1):

В php для этого есть [просмотр вперед и назад](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%E3%F3%EB%FF%F0%ED%FB%E5_%E2%FB%F0%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%FF#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4):

```
/(?<=:)[\w\-]+(?=:)/
```

`[\w\-]+` - подстрока, которая вам нужна,

`(?<=:)` - символ двоеточия до подстроки (он не захватывается в результат),

`(?=:)` - символ двоеточия после подстроки (он не захватывается в результат).

Пример работы https://regex101.com/r/M3y0ZK/1

P.S. Правда в таком виде будет и такой захват https://regex101.com/r/M3y0ZK/2